# MDX RANK Calulated Measure has 1 for every row

Tags: mdx

I'm trying to create a calculated measure in an MDX query that gets the rank for a dimension ordered by a measure.  The problem is that for each row all I get is 1 or, the count of the dimension if I change the sort order.

Here is my measure

```
MEMBER [Measures].[Approved wk to wk Rank] AS RANK (
  [FRR Group Matrix].[Group Name].CurrentMember,
  ORDER(
    [FRR Group Matrix].[Group Name].[Group Name].ALLMEMBERS, [Measures].[Approved wk to wk %], BDESC
  ),
  [Measures].[Approved wk to wk %]
)
```

My measures are in my columns, and my dimensions in rows.  Here is where I define my rows, and where I believe I have the problem:

```
{ ([FRR Group Matrix].[Group Name].[Group Name].ALLMEMBERS 
   * [FRR Group Matrix].[FRRCode].[FRRCode].ALLMEMBERS ) } ON ROWS
```

If I change to the following I will get a good rank, but I still want to keep both columns

```
{ [FRR Group Matrix].[Group Name].[Group Name].ALLMEMBERS } ON ROWS
```

So how can I get my rank to work with both tuples?

Comment: Maybe there is a dependency between both row attributes? Then using `ORDER([FRR Group Matrix].[Group Name].[Group Name].ALLMEMBERS, ([Measures].[Approved wk to wk %], [FRR Group Matrix].[FRRCode].[All]), BDESC )` might help, assuming `[FRR Group Matrix].[FRRCode].[All]` is the "all member" of the second attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the whole tuple in the `RANK` and `ORDER`.  `NONEMPTY` may not be necessary for your specific problem, but it will exclude blanks from your ranking, and probably speed up the execution time.

```
SET [X] AS
  ORDER(
      NONEMPTY(
         [FRR Group Matrix].[Group Name].[Group Name]
         * 
         [FRR Group Matrix].[FRRCode].[FRRCode], 
         [Measures].[Approved wk to wk %]
      ), 
      [Measures].[Approved wk to wk %], 
      BDESC
    )
  MEMBER [Measures].[Approved wk to wk Rank] AS 
    RANK (
      (
       [FRR Group Matrix].[Group Name].CurrentMember,
       [FRR Group Matrix].[FRRCode].CurrentMember
      ),
    [X], 
    [Measures].[Approved wk to wk %]
  )
```

Comment: @danielGimenez - `NONEMPTY` will probably make this script quicker irrespective of application, so I'm a little unconvinced by the edit you made.

Comment: revised.  It would be great if you could explain why putting the who tuple fixed the problem.

Comment: ...seems like it was the combination of those two hierarchies that you wanted to rank, so important to include in the `ORDER` section and also in the `RANK`'s first argument (not a great explanation sorry - @FrankPI can you help explain why this solution worked?)